# Unable to view word documents and excel sheet attachments in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, attachments

When i am trying to open attachments of a list item (MS word file /Excel sheet) in SharePoint online, it is redirecting to .....WopiFrame.aspx (trying to open with Microsoft Word Online), but the page stays blank.
I later came to know that Microsoft Word Online/Microsoft Excel online cannot  open older version of the documents like MS Word/Excel 2003/2007/2010/2013....
Is there a fix for this?

Other attachments like PDfs/ Pngs/Jpgs are opening in the client browser.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tested older versions of word or excel. However, I would suggest to activate the (Open Documents in Client Applications by Default) feature. Providing that the users have office suite installed on their machines.

Check this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837425.aspx), it will help you out

Updated: Have you also selected this option from the library settings - Advanced Settings

[image]

Comment: Hi Ahmed.... Thanks for your response.... "Open Documents in Client Applications by Default" site collection feature is already in activated state. Also, Office suite is installed on the client machines where i am trying this.